# Type Package for Python 3 in Google Cloud is returning error

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, type-hinting

For a piece of code I'm using the `typing` package from pythons standard library. My local machine is on Python 3.7 and it runs without errors; however, when I try to run it on a Google Cloud VM instance which runs on Python 3.5.3, it gives an invalid syntax error. I've looked around and it said to use Python2.7 type hints but the examples given were mainly geared towards functions and not classes. here is the code that I have:

```
class TrainConfig(typing.NamedTuple):
    T: int
    train_size: int
    batch_size: int
    loss_func: typing.Callable


class TrainData(typing.NamedTuple):
    feats: np.ndarray
    targs: np.ndarray
```

Here is the error given:

```
T: int
 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are called "class attribute annotations" and there is not a direct translation into type comments, as you need to provide an initial value:

```
class TrainConfig(typing.NamedTuple):
    T = ... # type: int
    train_size = ... # type: int
    batch_size = ... # type: int
    loss_func = ... # type: typing.Callable


class TrainData(typing.NamedTuple):
    feats = ... # type: np.ndarray
    targs = ... # type: np.ndarray
```

However, it's acceptable to set the initial value to `None`. From https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-comments:

> In stubs it may be useful to declare the existence of a variable without giving it an initial value. This can be done using [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526) variable annotation syntax:
>
> `from typing import IO`
>    `stream: IO[str]`
>
> The above syntax is acceptable in stubs for all versions of Python. However, in non-stub code for versions of Python 3.5 and earlier there is a special case:
>
> `from typing import IO`
>    `stream = None  # type: IO[str]`
>
> Type checkers should not complain about this (despite the value `None` not matching the given type), nor should they change the inferred type to `Optional[...]` (despite the rule that does this for annotated arguments with a default value of `None`). The assumption here is that other code will ensure that the variable is given a value of the proper type, and all uses can assume that the variable has the given type.